# Sort product using ajax in selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, sorting

I want to sort products using a selection box with ajax. But the product won't display and I don't know how to fix it. I think it could be the URL issue (or maybe more) but I don't know.
Here's my full code:

View

```
<form name="sortProducts" id="sortProducts">
 <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="{{ route('men') }}">
 <select id="sort" name="sort">
    <option value="product_relevance" @if (request()->sort == "product_relevance") selected @endif>Relevance</option>
    <option value="product_price_low_high" @if (request()->sort == "product_price_low_high") selected @endif>Price: Low to High</option>
    <option value="product_price_high_low" @if (request()->sort == "product_price_high_low") selected @endif>Price: High to Low</option>
    <option value="product_latest" @if (request()->sort == "product_latest") selected @endif>Latest Arrivals</option>
 </select>
</form>

<div class="filter_products col-9">
  <-- list products -->
</div>
```

Script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$("#sort").on('change', function(){
 var sort = $(this).val();
 var url = $('#url').val()
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "post",
   data: {sort:sort, url:url},
   success: function(data){
   $('.filter_products').html(data);
  }
 })
});
```

Controller

```
if($request->ajax()){
  $data = $request->all;

  $products = new Product();
  $products = $products->where('gender_id', '=', 1);

  // sorting product
  if ($data['sort'] == "product_price_low_high") {
      $products->orderBy('productprice','asc');
  } elseif ($data['sort'] == "product_price_high_low") {
      $products->orderBy('productprice','desc');
  } elseif ($data['sort'] == "product_latest") {
      $products->orderBy('products.id','desc');
  } elseif ($data['sort'] == "product_relevance") {
      $products;
  }

   return view('menpage/men', compact('products'));
    
}
```

Comment: Did you check what `data` has ?

Comment: sorry but how to check it?

Comment: Use : `console.log(data)`  ... you will see result inside your browser console .

Comment: ive tried and it says `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/men 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Make sure your controller supports `POST` request  .Also , see if you need to add csrf token as well because its `POST` request .

Comment: yeah... still no have idea